# Search remote drives in Gnome

Tags: gnome, 20.04, nautilus, search

I'm using the standard file manager Nautilus in Ubuntu 20.04 to search a remote disk drive (it's a computer on the same small local network connected via SMB). Nautilus won't search beyond the current folder. How to overcome this issue and search as deep as locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefrences>Search and Preview

First section Search in subfolders. By default its on this computer only. Change to All locations[image]